# SCCM Client Un-install Script won't work

Tags: sccm

I have written this pretty basic script to uninstall the SCCM 2012 Client but it refuses to work. I am pretty sure it's due to the elevated privileges required to access the CCMSetup folder.
How else can I get this to work?

```
$comp = Read-Host "Enter Computer Name"

if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp -Count 1)

{ 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock { Start-Process powershell -Verb runas -ArgumentList 'C:\windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe /uninstall'

}


Else

{

Write-Host "Computer $comp is not Reachable"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `ccmclean.exe` program.

Mind you, It is not the advised way to uninstall sccm agent, but it still works.

Search for it in the sms 2003 toolkit, the command line for a silent uninstallation is:

```
ccmclean.exe /q /all
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

When using the **Invoke-Command**, use the -credential switch.

```
Invoke-Command -Computername PCNAMEHERE -credential DOMAIN\USERID -scriptblock {start-process "c:\windows\ccmsetup\ccmsetup.exe" -ArgumentList ("/uninstall")}
```

More examples are available here:
[Invoke-Command (TechNet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In the client machine,

Start > RUN > CMD as Administrator and 
Cd C:\Windows\CCMsetup\ {......}\

Execute: msiexec /x client.msi